# How to know currently in a phone call or not programmatically

Tags: android

Is there any way to know the device is currently in a phone call at the moment?
I know we can set a broadcast receiver to get phone call state.

I am asking is there any other solution to instantly know whether the device is on a call at the moment

Comment: you can know when a call is incoming or when an outgoing call is trying to be made. i don't know whether you can actually check whether you're currently in a call though.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code:-

```
var phoneStateListener: PhoneStateListener = object : PhoneStateListener() {
        override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, incomingNumber: String) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                // phone ringing
            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
               // phone idle
            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                //A call is dialing, active or on hold
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber)
        }
    }
```